# Qual è il significato di "defilato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto:

> Uscí al torrente e i soldati riaccostarono la porta. Il tenente restò fermo un attimo solo, poi si riportò in fretta verso il centro del cortile. Ma anche lí non si senti di rimanere, quasi che la raffica potesse uccidere anche lui attraverso il muro. Si diresse a grandi passi al **defilato**, verso la mensa ufficiali. Come ne raggiunse lo spigolo, crepitò la raffica.

Non capisco il significato di "defilato" nel brano precedente. Ho cercato il vocabolo in alcuni dizionari e ho trovato che si tratta di un aggettivo col significato di qualcosa che si trova  appartata o sottratta all'osservazione. Tuttavia, qui sembra che se ne fa uso come sostantivo. Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il suo senso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buongiorno Charo, per estensione l'aggettivo **defilato** viene qui utilizzato come sostantivo per indicare una zona defilata, appartata.
Nel caso più specifico riferito al contesto in cui si svolge la scena, ovvero un contesto militare, il termine **defilato** indica un posto o una zona defilata alla vista del nemico.